# Is there any spin-resolved time-resolved angle-resolved photoemission spectroscopy (ARPES)?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, spectroscopy

Has the technique of *both* spin- and time-resolved angle-resolved photoemission spectroscopy (ARPES) been realized and applied anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of high-efficiency spin detectors with time-resolved ARPES systems would provide new opportunities for simultaneously acquiring time-resolved and spin-resolved ARPES spectra.

For example, a high-efficiency ARTOF-VLEED spin spectrometer that combines a VLEED spin detector with an ARTOF analyser has been developed. This high-efficiency spectrometer enables simultaneous spinresolved, time-resolved and angle-resolved photoemission with pulsed lasers.

We use a time-of-flight electron analyzer (Scienta ARTOF 10k), which provides three-dimensional dispersion (energy and two components of momentum) without the need to tilt the sample. The large, conical acceptance angle of the detector (up to ±18°) is particularly useful for obtaining both time-resolved and angle-resolved photoemission spectra with fast data acquisition.

References:

Lv, B., Qian, T. & Ding, H. Angle-resolved photoemission spectroscopy and its application to topological materials. Nat Rev Phys 1, 609–626 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1038/s42254-019-0088-5

Sie, E.J., Rohwer, T., Lee, C. et al. Time-resolved XUV ARPES with tunable 24–33 eV laser pulses at 30 meV resolution. Nat Commun 10, 3535 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-019-11492-3

Comment: Minor comment to answer (v1): Those are usually called references not citations.